# iOS and NSDate functions for last 7 days

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have the following code to generate the current date in order to allow me to show the number of steps taken today.

However I would like to display the previous 7 days data that is stored, but am unsure how to make the date query show each of the last 7 days so that I can then make the 7 queries. I am thinking it is possible to write the code below 7 times, with a -1 -2 -3 etc. but am unsure where I would do the adjustment to get prior dates.

Could someone shed some light onto it for me?

```
// Calculate start of day

- (NSDate * )startDateOfToday
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Read the fine reference material on NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.  It's all there.

Comment: Take a look at [`-[NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:).

Comment: @bdesham - Though dateByAddingTimeInterval doesn't handle DST, et al.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply decrement `components.day` by the number of days you want to remove.  It's ok for it to go negative.  Example code:

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
        | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
        fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        NSLog(@"%d days before today = %@", i, date);
        --components.day;
    }
```

Output:

```
2013-12-04 12:37:33.876 7days[62698:303] 0 days before today = 2013-12-04 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.877 7days[62698:303] 1 days before today = 2013-12-03 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.877 7days[62698:303] 2 days before today = 2013-12-02 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.877 7days[62698:303] 3 days before today = 2013-12-01 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.877 7days[62698:303] 4 days before today = 2013-11-30 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.877 7days[62698:303] 5 days before today = 2013-11-29 06:00:00 +0000
2013-12-04 12:37:33.878 7days[62698:303] 6 days before today = 2013-11-28 06:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: This works well. If I wanted to do just one day, say yesterday, how would you achieve it without the array ?

Comment: I didn't use an array.  I used a loop to subtract one day at a time.  If you just want yesterday, decrement `components.day` by one.  If you want seven days ago, decrement `components.day` by seven.  Then, after updating the components in whatever way you want, call `[calendar dateFromComponents:components]` to get the corresponding date.

Comment: Sorry. I meant loop not array! You mention decrement components.day which I could do --components.day the number of times I wished to reduce by. However is there a way to do this in one line where I just say the number of days? If so, what syntax. So something like components.day:-3 or similar?

Comment: `components.day -= 7;`